# Select and sort on two columns MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

So, my code looks like this

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM threads WHERE forum_id = '$id' ORDER BY type,posted DESC") or                                 
die(mysql_error());
```

"posted" is the value of time() and is selected decreased to put the latest one at the top.
"type" contains either 1 or 2. If it's 2, the thread is pinned. Currently, it sorts after posted but those which should be at the top (pinned) are at the bottom. Is there any fix that I'm missing?

Comment: change DESC to ASC? Or use GROUP? AND use PDO/mysqli instead of mysql to be safe.

Comment: @John tried changing from DESC to ASC. Haven't tried GROUP thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: `ORDER BY type DESC, posted DESC`

By default, it sorts ascending. You need to specify the order for both fields you would like to order by.

[ORDER BY Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Comment: Thanks! It works! Feel kinda stupid, thought I tried that but apparently not :P

Comment: @user2065518, if Sean was helpful to you please tick his answer as the right one. It will also help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that the asc/desc in an order by applies to each individual field, not the entire order by clause.

```
ORDER BY type DESC, posted ASC
```

MySQL can also accept arbitrary logic for order by, so for more complicated sort requirements, you could have something like

```
ORDER BY IF(type=2, 0, 1) AS pinned ASC, posted DESC
```

as long the arbitrary logic returns something that's trivially sortable (e.g. a number or a string), there's no limit to how complicated the sorting can be.

Comment: Didn't know a lot of that.. +1.